# Как задать размер padding-bottom для элемента li?

Tags: html, css, дизайн

Маркеры добавила через CSS ввиде изображения. Элементу li задала свойство padding-bottom, оно применяется для текста но для маркеров не применяется. Разными способами старалась решать проблему, но не получилось

```css
.about__right li {
  background: url(img/mark.png) 0px no-repeat;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.about__right li i {
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__right">
  <h3>SOME WORDS <span class="h3-bold">ABOUT US</span></h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus ex quidem maiores ullam quis, at asperiores minus ad eaque maxime possimus .</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Mission - <i>We deliver uniqueness and quality</i></li>
    <li>Skills - <i>Delivering fast and excellent results</i></li>
    <li>Clients - <i>Satisfied clients thanks to our experience</i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Результат кода]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327154/how-do-i-add-spacemargin-bottom-between-the-lis-of-my-ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-position: 0px -10px;
```

Comment: -10px на 5px поменяла, тогда исправилось. Когда -10px маркеры почти исчезают. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте:

```
ul li{margin-bottom:10px;}
```

English Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327154/how-do-i-add-spacemargin-bottom-between-the-lis-of-my-ul

Comment: Решилась проблема. Спасибо. Если это(background-position: 0px 5px;) свойство добавить  в .about__right li{ } тогда тоже решается проблема.

Comment: Примите ответ который считаете наилучшим :)

Answer (score 0):

У вас маркер стал background - ом, только меняя ему позицию через "background-position" вы сможете его двигать. Падинги это внутренние отступы от элементов.

Comment: Да я знаю что pаdding это внутренний отступ. Просто я забыла что li это само по себе является блоком. Вот этот момент я перепутала. Поэтому либо через margin-bottom либо через background-position можно решать эту проблему. Спасибо @Oleksii Kovbasiuk